# In the following daemon the reciever thread is not recieving messages sent from sender thread via Rabbit MQ

Tags: c++, rabbitmq

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <amqp.h>
#include <amqp_tcp_socket.h>
#include <functional> // Include this header for std::ref

const std::string QUEUE_NAME = "hello_queue";
const std::string EXCHANGE_NAME = "hello_exchange";
const std::string ROUTING_KEY = "hello_routing_key";

std::string bytesToString(const amqp_bytes_t& bytes) {
    return std::string(static_cast<char*>(bytes.bytes), bytes.len);
}

std::string getQueueId(amqp_connection_state_t conn, const std::string& queueName) {
    amqp_queue_declare(conn, 1, amqp_cstring_bytes(queueName.c_str()), 0, 0, 0, 1, amqp_empty_table);
    amqp_rpc_reply_t reply = amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn);

    if (reply.reply_type == AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL) {
        amqp_queue_declare_ok_t* declare_ok = reinterpret_cast<amqp_queue_declare_ok_t*>(reply.reply.decoded);
        return bytesToString(declare_ok->queue);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error declaring queue" << std::endl;
        return "";
    }
}

int getMessageCount(amqp_connection_state_t conn, const std::string& queueName) {
    amqp_queue_declare(conn, 1, amqp_cstring_bytes(queueName.c_str()), 0, 0, 0, 1, amqp_empty_table);
    amqp_rpc_reply_t declare_reply = amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn);

    if (declare_reply.reply_type == AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL) {
        amqp_queue_declare_ok_t* declare_ok = reinterpret_cast<amqp_queue_declare_ok_t*>(declare_reply.reply.decoded);
        return static_cast<int>(declare_ok->message_count);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error declaring queue" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
void printQueueInfo(amqp_connection_state_t conn, const std::string& queueName) {
    std::string queueId = getQueueId(conn, queueName);
    int messageCount = getMessageCount(conn, queueName);

    if (!queueId.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Queue ID: " << queueId << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Number of messages in queue: " << messageCount << std::endl;
    }
}

void senderThread(amqp_connection_state_t conn) {
    std::cout << "starting senderThread: " << std::endl;
    // Declare exchange
    amqp_exchange_declare(conn, 1, amqp_cstring_bytes(EXCHANGE_NAME.c_str()),
                          amqp_cstring_bytes("direct"), 0, 0, 0, 0, amqp_empty_table);
    amqp_rpc_reply_t exchange_reply = amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn);
    if (exchange_reply.reply_type != AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL) {
        std::cerr << "Error declaring exchange senderThread" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    int counter = 2;
    while (counter--) {
        // Send message
        std::string message = "Hello, RabbitMQ!";
        amqp_basic_properties_t props;
        props._flags = AMQP_BASIC_CONTENT_TYPE_FLAG | AMQP_BASIC_DELIVERY_MODE_FLAG;
        props.content_type = amqp_cstring_bytes("text/plain");
        props.delivery_mode = 2;  // Persistent message

        amqp_basic_publish(conn, 1, amqp_cstring_bytes(EXCHANGE_NAME.c_str()),
                           amqp_cstring_bytes(ROUTING_KEY.c_str()), 0, 0, &props,
                           amqp_cstring_bytes(message.c_str()));
        std::cout << "Sent: " << message << std::endl;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    std::cout << "exiting senderThread: " << std::endl;
}
// Add a function to reconnect to RabbitMQ and reopen the channel
void reconnect(amqp_connection_state_t& conn) {
    // ... (reconnection logic)
    //amqp_connection_state_t conn = amqp_new_connection();
    std::cout << "starting reconnect: " << std::endl;
    amqp_socket_t *socket = amqp_tcp_socket_new(conn);
    amqp_socket_open(socket, "localhost", 5672);

    // Create channel
    amqp_channel_open(conn, 1);
    amqp_rpc_reply_t channel_reply = amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn);
    if (channel_reply.reply_type != AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening channel receiverThread" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}
void receiverThread(amqp_connection_state_t conn) {
    std::cout << "starting recieverThread: " << std::endl;

    // Declare queue
    amqp_queue_declare(conn, 1, amqp_cstring_bytes(QUEUE_NAME.c_str()), 0, 0, 0, 1,
                       amqp_empty_table);
    amqp_rpc_reply_t queue_reply = amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn);
    if (queue_reply.reply_type != AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL) {
        std::cerr << "Error declaring queue receiverThread" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "queue declared recieverThread: " << std::endl;

    // Bind queue to exchange
    amqp_queue_bind(conn, 1, amqp_cstring_bytes(QUEUE_NAME.c_str()),
                    amqp_cstring_bytes(EXCHANGE_NAME.c_str()),
                    amqp_cstring_bytes(ROUTING_KEY.c_str()), amqp_empty_table);
    amqp_rpc_reply_t bind_reply = amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn);
    if (bind_reply.reply_type != AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL) {
        std::cerr << "Error binding queue to exchange receiverThread" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "queue bound recieverThread: " << std::endl;


    int counter = 2;
    while (counter--) {
            std::cout << "counter recieverThread: " << counter << std::endl;
        // Receive message
        amqp_envelope_t envelope;
        amqp_maybe_release_buffers(conn);
        amqp_rpc_reply_t consume_reply = amqp_consume_message(conn, &envelope, nullptr, 0);
        if (consume_reply.reply_type != AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL) {
            std::cout << "Error consuming message receiverThread: " << consume_reply.reply_type << std::endl;
            if (consume_reply.reply_type == AMQP_CHANNEL_CLOSE_METHOD) {
                    amqp_channel_close(conn, 1, AMQP_REPLY_SUCCESS);
                    std::cout << "Channel closed by server. Attempting to reopen." << std::endl;
                    reconnect(conn);
                    continue;
            }
            continue;
        }

        //std::string message(
            //static_cast<char *>(envelope.message.body.bytes), envelope.message.body.len);
        std::string message(
                        static_cast<const char*>(envelope.message.body.bytes),
                        static_cast<const char*>(envelope.message.body.bytes) + envelope.message.body.len
                        );
        std::cout << "Received: " << message << std::endl;

        amqp_destroy_envelope(&envelope);
    }

    std::cout << "exiting recieverThread: " << std::endl;
}
int main() {

        // Connect to RabbitMQ server
        // Connect to RabbitMQ server
          amqp_connection_state_t conn = amqp_new_connection();
        amqp_socket_t *socket = amqp_tcp_socket_new(conn);
        amqp_socket_open(socket, "localhost", 5672);

        if (!socket) {
                std::cerr << "Could not create TCP socket" << std::endl;
                return 1;
        }

        amqp_rpc_reply_t login_reply = amqp_login(conn, "/", 0, 131072, 0, AMQP_SASL_METHOD_PLAIN, "guest", "guest");
        if (login_reply.reply_type != AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL) {
                std::cerr << "Error logging in" << std::endl;
                return 1;
        }

        amqp_channel_open(conn, 1);
        amqp_rpc_reply_t channel_reply = amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn);
        if (channel_reply.reply_type != AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL) {
                std::cerr << "Error opening channel main" << std::endl;
                return 1;
        }

        // Print queue information
        printQueueInfo(conn, QUEUE_NAME);

        // Create sender and receiver threads using lambda functions
        std::thread sender([conn]() { senderThread(conn); });
        std::thread receiver([conn]() { receiverThread(conn); });

        // Wait for threads to finish
        sender.join();
        receiver.join();
                 // Close the connection
        amqp_channel_close(conn, 1, AMQP_REPLY_SUCCESS);
        amqp_connection_close(conn, AMQP_REPLY_SUCCESS);
        amqp_destroy_connection(conn);

        return 0;
}
```

For compilation I am using the following command

```
g++ -o mydaemon3 -g mydaemon3.cpp -lrabbitmq -pthread
```

For running this daemon I am using

```
gdb ./mydaemon3
```

The output is as follows

```
❯ gdb ./mydaemon3
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./mydaemon3...
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/aniruddha/Documents/GitHub/RabbitMQ/mydaemon3 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Queue ID: hello_queue
Number of messages in queue: 97
[New Thread 0x7ffff7681700 (LWP 264445)]
starting senderThread: 
[New Thread 0x7ffff6e80700 (LWP 264446)]
starting recieverThread: 
Sent: Hello, RabbitMQ!
queue declared recieverThread: 
queue bound recieverThread: 
counter recieverThread: 1
Sent: Hello, RabbitMQ!
exiting senderThread: 
[Thread 0x7ffff7681700 (LWP 264445) exited]
^C
Thread 1 "mydaemon3" received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
__pthread_clockjoin_ex (threadid=140737335789312, thread_return=0x0, clockid=<optimized out>, abstime=<optimized out>, block=<optimized out>) at pthread_join_common.c:145
145 pthread_join_common.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) frame
#0  __pthread_clockjoin_ex (threadid=140737335789312, thread_return=0x0, clockid=<optimized out>, abstime=<optimized out>, block=<optimized out>)
    at pthread_join_common.c:145
145 in pthread_join_common.c
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 264441] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

I have checked whether rabbit mq server is up

[image]

However the following log is not getting printed on reciever thread , would be grateful if anyone could provide directions on how to proceed in debugging this issue

```
Received: Hello, RabbitMQ!
```